# Non UTF-8 text being detected as UTF-8

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

**I´ve found the solution**
Apparently hostgator phpmyadmin doesn't have the UTF-8 header on it.

Recently I moved my web forum from a development local machine to a production server (Hostgator, shared), but something weird is going on, everytime we pump data out of the database and display it we get replacement characters *in lieu* of special Portuguese charcters (á, é, ê, ó, ç and so on), even though the database is set to use UTF-8 (on the database, tables, rows and connection). When we pass the same exact string to a `mb_detect_encoding` it says that it is a valid UTF-8 string.

The only thing that makes the data from the database display properly is to remove the `<meta charset="utf8">` from the HTML, but then all the other special characters (from text that isn't from the database) gets garbled.

What the HTML is going on?

PHP 5.2
MySQL 5.5.30-30.2

About the posible duplicate question, I (personally, of course) don't think that it's a fit, because that other question assumes prior knowledge and work with text encoding.

Comment: I'm confused. So what encoding *is* the text in? Post the result of `echo bin2hex($string)` here to let us analyze it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply deceze, this is the hex for the string "Café"
436166e9